# What is the required format for DateTime values when importing DevOps Work Items using CSV?

Tags: azure-devops

To help automate the creation of a monthly work set we're attempting to take the 'January' set of User Stories and Tasks, adjust them for February and then import them using the CSV import in DevOps.

We have added the 'Due Date' field to the Task record in our modified process so that we can track weekly deliveries, using the Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.DueDate field used elsewhere.

Everything seems to be fine with picking up parent items and assigning users but no matter what I do I cannot get the importer to accept the datetime format for the Due Date field.

I started off with the format from the 'Export To CSV' functionality (US Format, 12 hour clock) e.g. 2/3/2022 12:00 PM and the importer reports `The value for field 'Due Date' is not of the right type.`

I have since tested about 30 combinations of date and time formats to no avail; UK (browser locale), US and universal formats and it's the same error every time.

I suspect that there is a very specific format that I have managed to miss so far, as I see the same error when trying to set a Target Date for a Feature, which is in the default Agile process.

Can anyone share a working format, or insight into whether it may be affected by my region or the region of the DevOps instance?

Comment: try this: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffz`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 2022-02-02T17:00:00.00000000 for 5PM on the 2nd February was not accepted, unfortunately. Same error.

Comment: Nor did putting a Z on the end to indicate UTC: 2022-02-02T17:00:00.0000000Z

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
,7/14/2022 12:00 AM,
```

I discovered that I was using Excel to create the CSV file and it was treating it as a "Date" field and doing something weird to it, which wasn't accepted by DevOps:

```
,7/14/2022 0:00,
```

In Excel, I just changed the format of the cells to "test" (making sure they were not set to "Date").

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the date format to English (US) so that it was written in that fantastic backwards way. When it was imported into Excel it first showed the US way,but when I checked the first record in preview it had converted it to the format that makes sense.  Thanks Microsoft

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).